# Verisioning a Webapi .net-core using with VersionByNamespaceConvention and not being forced to use RouteAttribute on Controllers

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing, aspnet-api-versioning

The idea is to have a versioned API by URL like this:

- /api/v1/weatherforecast
- /api/v2/weatherforecast
- /api/v3/weatherforecast

My namespace is the following:

[image: NameSpace Versioning]

On the Startup I have this code to register the versioning:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddApiVersioning(
        options =>
        {
            // reporting api versions will return the headers "api-supported-versions" and "api-deprecated-versions"
            options.ReportApiVersions = true;
            // automatically applies an api version based on the name of the defining controller's namespace
            options.Conventions.Add(new VersionByNamespaceConvention());
        });
}
```

So I wanted to remove the **"[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]"** Attribute in every Controller is this possible?

I was trying to map the controllers using something like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "api",
            pattern: "api/v{version:apiVersion}/{controller}/{id?}"
            );
    });
}
```

But when I run the code it gives the following error:

*Action 'ApiVersioning.Api.V3.Controllers.WeatherForecastController.Get (ApiVersioning)' does not have an attribute route. Action methods on controllers annotated with ApiControllerAttribute must be attribute routed.'*

So can I add an implicit routing convention for all Controllers that removes the need of the RouteAttribute on top of every Controller?

Comment: If you remove [ApiController] attribute,can your project work well?How did you custom `VersionByNamespaceConvention`?

Comment: VersionByNamespaceConcention is implemented by https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning.If I remove [ApiController] I think controllers are not registered, and I receive 404 when trying to access it

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are seeing is a restriction of the built-in API Explorer. It only supports *Attribute Routing*. If you don't need that for documentation, then it shouldn't be a problem.

Unlike the ASP.NET of old, there is no distinction between a *UI Controller* and an *API Controller*. However, there are certain behaviors developers expect between them. API Versioning requires that **all** controllers are versioned, even if implicitly via the default API version (and otherwise undecorated). This behavior was undesirable for those mixing UI and APIs together. Once the `[ApiController]` attribute was introduced, there was finally a way to reliably identify whether a controller is for an API.

To test this, you can simply change `ApiVersioningOptions.UseApiBehavior = false`. This will revert back to the old behavior. Bear in mind that this will result in all controllers being versioned.

The alternate approach is to implement **IApiControllerSpecification** or **IApiControllerFilter**. Typically you only need **IApiControllerSpecification** as the filter is an aggregation of all specifications. Register your specification(s) or filter with the DI container. The implementation of a specification decides whether a controller is for APIs given a **ControllerModel**. There is a built-in specification that looks for `[ApiController]`. You might create one that looks for **ControllerBase** as the base class or use some other mechanism such as prefix in the route template or containing namespace. The choice is up to you. The specification will allow you to use your own conventions without having to use `[ApiController]`.

You could also use a base class for all controllers with the attribution you want in a single place. It's not exactly the same as using a standard route convention, but it will achieve a similar result. You may need that approach if you expect to support API documentation.